# Identify the first month in a dataframe where the value is greater than zero

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have a dataframe which contains products, countries, sales and the month of sale...How do i identify the month the product was launched in that country (when was the first month with sales greater than zero). I have tried if's and group by and rank combination

[image: Dataframe Example with desired column 'Month of launch']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter out sales equals (or lesser) than 0, then you group by country, and take the first row; then you need the month of launch.

In code this is summarized as:

```py
>>> months = df[df['sales'] > 0].groupby('country').first()['month of launch']
country
c1    month 1
c2    month 1
Name: month of launch, dtype: object
```

If you need the list version (this is a `pandas.Series`), you can use the function `tolist()` on `months`.